# Speed of atoms being pushed away

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, speed-of-light

It is said that it is impossible to calculate one-way speed of light.
I have doubts in my small theory and I would like someone to correct me because I lack in knowledge in physics, and I'm surely wrong somewhere or everywhere.
There's something I have imagined and it worries me a bit to not know why it wouldn't work:

Let's imagine there is two objects called "A" and "B":

"A" has a clock.
"A" and "B" a device that can measures the force of traction between "A" and "B" and vice-versa.
"B" can throw light.

These two objects are linked together by a simple wire (no electricity).

```
"A" ----------------------------------------------------------- "B"
```

Now we cut the middle of the wire named "/".

```
"A" -----------------------------/------------------------------ "B"
```

When the wire breaks,

both "A" and "B" detects a lower amount of traction.

When this is detected, "A" starts its clock, and "B" throws light at "A".

"A" clock stops when light is recieved.

I suppose now "A" have the time that the light has travelled for one way and we know the speed.

But I realize that I'm assuming (that is maybe where is my mistake) that the wire itself when it breaks;
goes "transmitting information" to both objects "A" and "B" where atoms are being pushed away at the same speed.

Since nothing goes faster than the speed of light, I guess that "information" should go at maximum at the speed of light?
Is the "information" into the wire travels at the same speed for both "A" and "B" ?

Comment: The pulse in the wire travels at the speed of sound, not instantly. Sound travels faster through wire than it does through air, but it's *much* slower than light.

Answer (score 0):

The general principle of your suggestion is that one might use a mechanical device to trigger the emission of a light pulse in one place and the simultaneous start of a counter at another. The problem is that the transmission of a mechanical impulse down a wire or a rod is ultimately governed by electromagnetic interactions between the particles that comprise it, so you are assuming that the mechanical impulses that travel one way to trigger the emission and the other way to trigger the timer do indeed travel at the same speeds, which defeats the purpose of the experiment.